# how to get new mysql connector for c#

Tags: c#, mysql, connector

I have an application that has been using the MySQL connector without problem until recently.  I have been packaging MySql.Data.dll with each client app installation.  Now I get error:  Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.  So I'm thinking I need new MySQL connector.  So I go to http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/ and see there is no longer one for c sharp.  Then I go to http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html and see that I have to install MySQL on my developer box and possibly every client this application is installed on.  I really hope I'm missing something.  How do I get a new MySql.Data.dll to include as a reference in my c sharp app?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you read the licensing restrictions for the MySql connector, they are pretty strict and has pretty broad implications for your app.

Comment: well it won't matter much if I can't use them right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get MySQL.Data [from NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/):

```
Install-Package MySql.Data
```

If you must get it from MySQL's website directly, [it's still there](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).  It's actually the top item on the page you linked, it's just called "ADO.NET Driver for MySQL (Connector/NET)".

Comment: I'd rather get it from MySQL if possible.  How is this different that what is at MySQL site?

Comment: That *is* from MySql, they publish the package and is the recommended way to get it. The difference is you don't have to make your users run an installer. NuGet is preferred, its easy to update packages and move from one development system to the next.

Comment: It's a lot easier to get it from NuGet (as Ron mentions, it's still from MySQL!), but you can still get it from MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: ok ok I'm sold ... so I assume I need to install the nuget package manager?  then when I do an install-package MySQL.data ... does a MySql.Data.dll pop out somewhere that I include with my app or is it different now?

Comment: You don't need to install MySql.Data.  It will be in your bin directory, along with the other references.  An installer should package it up automatically.