# How to connect to mysql with C# (simple program)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am a beginner in C # and I intend to create a simple program to check the connection to the mysql server (in this case I am using xampp, so the connection is local).
The problem is that the connection to the mysql server does not work, so the "Can not open connection!" box pops up. I appreciate all the explanations. thank you :)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn;
        string server = "localhost";
        string database = "test";
        string uid = "root";
        string password = "";   //im using xampp
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You've posted some code. What's wrong with it? Please read [ask].

Comment: Hi - Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  In particular, please 1) State your question explicitly ("What are you asking?"), 2) Copy/paste the exact error message (if applicable), 3) Specify where in your example code the problem is occurring (if possible).  ALSO: I assume you went into MSVS > NuGet and downloaded the MySQL library for .Net, correct?

Comment: Put a break point where you are catching the exception `ex` and see what the error message is. That will give you an idea as to what went wrong and is causing the code execution to throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you for updating your post, stating the problem:  "Can not open connection!" box pops up.  SUGGESTION: Modify your "catch()" block: `MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection: " + ex.Message);`.  ALSO print out the entire exception in your MSVS debugger and copy/paste the full traceback (with error message) into your post.

Comment: I did not know this way to detect errors. [IMAGE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lMZyOuxcTlridhvqhnj-s8lLDSvfmsDp/view)

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, it sounds like your C# program might be trying to use the SQL Server driver to talk to a MySQL database.  That won't work :)

Look at any of these links:

- [MySQL Connector/Net Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/)
- [MySQL C# tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/)
- [Connect C# to MySQL](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL)

At a minimum, you'll also need to get the MySQL driver (e.g. from NuGet):

- [how to get new mysql connector for c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268338/how-to-get-new-mysql-connector-for-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem after a while i find out i can not use SqlConnection. SqlConnection is for SQL Server i need to install **MySql.Data** from NuGet:

> **Install-Package MySql.Data** in your Package Manager Console

then i can create MySqlConnection object and connect to your database:

```
System.Data.IDbConnection cnn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("my Connection String");
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
        cnn.Close();
    }
```